# Get person profile properties by name

Tags: javascript, client-object-model, person

Is there a quick solution of getting someone's user profile given just their name?
I want to get the mysites url of the user and I only have their name.

Comment: A name is in no way unique so you will have a hard time getting that solution stable. Is there not a better way, like using the login name or similar you can use?

Answer (score 1):

As Robert suggested there is no way to ensure you are getting the correct person with only `DisplayName`. Below code is not tested

```
var searchTerm = 'Name';
var sourceId = 'PeopleResultSourceId'; //"B09A7990-05EA-4AF9-81EF-EDFAB16C4E31"
//Method to fetch all the users
function getAllUsers() {
    clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    //Building Keyword query for the search
    var keywordQuery = new Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Search.Query.KeywordQuery(clientContext);
    keywordQuery.set_queryText(searchTerm);
    keywordQuery.set_sourceId(sourceId);
    keywordQuery.set_rowLimit(1);
    keywordQuery.set_trimDuplicates(false);

    var searchExecutor = new Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Search.Query.SearchExecutor(clientContext);
    results = searchExecutor.executeQuery(keywordQuery);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onQuerySuccess, onQueryError);
}

function onQuerySuccess() { 
   $.each(results.m_value.ResultTables[0].ResultRows, function () {
        fetchProfilePropertiesForUsers(users.push(this.AccountName); 

        //Break since we are assuming the first user is what we are looking for
    }); 
}

function fetchProfilePropertiesForUsers(accountName) {
    $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl + "/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetPropertiesFor(accountName=@v)?@v='" + accountName + "'",
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        },
        success: function (data) {
            var userUrl = data.d.UserUrl;
            alert(userUrl);
        },
        error: function (err) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(err));
        }
    });
}
```